# OnClick event for calling javascript function syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm going to ask an easy one here for those who are very familiar with this kind of syntax. Unfortunately I'm not, and I'm having a hard time with using single quotes and double quotes for raising a javascript method in an OnClick event. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenWindow(workItemId) { ... }
</script>
```

**EDIT:** copy-paste mistake, forgot the server block quotes `<%# %>`

```
<asp:Image ID="imgDescription" ImageUrl="../Images/Tooltip_t.gif" runat="server" OnClick='OpenWindow('<%# Eval("WorkItemId") %>' );' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
onclick='<%# "OpenWindow(" + Eval("WorkItemId") + ");" %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this ?

```
<asp:Image ID="imgDescription" ImageUrl="../Images/Tooltip_t.gif" runat="server" OnClick="OpenWindow(Eval(\"WorkItemId\"));" />
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use screening slashes with your quotes like: \"